# LWUIT textfield

Tags: textfield, lwuit

if method setMaxSize(1) is called, tactile keypad only inputs first character .e.g. can only write A in "ABC or D in "DEF" etc any ideas on how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. I haven't tried this myself but I can see why this would fail. 
I doubt whether there is a simple solution for this other that overriding the text field input and implementing the single character behavior yourself. Just set the max length to 2 and override the `insertChar` method by invoking `super.setText()` with the given char.